# Wifi option missing from Kubutu 16.04, can't connect to wifi networks

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, broadcom

Network Manager System tray menu doesn't show option for wifi. It shows airplane mode button but wifi button which should be next to it is missing. I have just installed Kubuntu 16.04 and this problem is there since the install. I got a detailed analysis report on computer network by running command:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info && kate wireless-info.txt
```

Result:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 29 Aug 2016 02:03 IST +0530

Booted last: 29 Aug 2016 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

/usr/share/xsessions/plasma

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:380a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0621]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              565248  0
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          212992  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    20480  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  2 i915,ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:10.100.96.21  Bcast:10.100.96.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f122:aaa3:b379:30a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:123264 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:76442 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:148168672 (148.1 MB)  TX bytes:6745965 (6.7 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.100.96.4     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0
10.100.56.21    10.100.96.4     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp1s0
10.100.96.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp1s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp1s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search rukus.daiict.ac.in

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

NetworkManager

Running:

root      2497     1  0 00:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp1s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
    GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
    GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
    GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
    GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       7c0db5ef-249f-422a-8159-0f7cdb7b77d4
    GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
    GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
    CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
    CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
    CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
    WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   7c0db5ef-249f-422a-8159-0f7cdb7b77d4 | Wired connection 1
    IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.100.96.21/24
    IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.100.96.4
    IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.100.56.21/32, nh = 10.100.96.4, mt = 100
    IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
    IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.100.56.27
    IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.100.56.25
    IP4.DNS[3]:                             10.100.56.40
    IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          rukus.daiict.ac.in
    IP4.WINS[1]:                            10.100.56.21
    IP4.WINS[2]:                            10.100.56.15
    DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 10.100.56.27 10.100.56.25 10.100.56.40
    DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 10.100.96.21
    DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        filename = bpbatch
    DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 10.100.56.21
    DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        netbios_name_servers = 10.100.56.21 10.100.56.15
    DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 10.100.96.255
    DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 37800
    DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
    DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       routers = 10.100.96.4
    DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 21600
    DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       domain_name = rukus.daiict.ac.in
    DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_routers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       expiry = 1472452891
    DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 10.100.96.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = 10.100.56.85
    DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 43200
    DHCP4.OPTION[32]:                       requested_host_name = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[33]:                       next_server = 10.100.56.18
    IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::f122:aaa3:b379:30a/64
    IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Hotspot | type=wifi | autoconnect=false | permissions=user:parth:;
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=CyberKnight
[ipv4] method=shared
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   24.659458] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   24.659466] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   24.704132] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link up
[   24.704142] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

[image: This image will show how wifi option is missing]

Please help me as I am unable to access wifi networks on Kubuntu but they work perfectly fine on windows 10 which is dual booted with Kubuntu. Can anybody suggest a solution?

** I don't refrain from saying that this is not a duplicate question, but being a new user it is difficult for me to relate between wifi problem and the question about "Required key not available". Nevertheless, my issue is resolved and Thanks a lot for help! :)

Comment: What is the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl`? Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available. Thanks for reviewing question.